# Обрезается модальное окно при нехватке места

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, flexbox

Попытаюсь объяснить, что я имею ввиду.
У нас есть блок `.modal`, он служит затемнением фона, внутри данного блока находится блок `.modal__content`, в котором может находится что угодно, любой высоты. Нужно чтобы блок `.modal` имел полосу прокрутки, если `.modal__content` не вмещается в видимую область. Но происходит то, что `.modal__content` выходит за верхнюю границу браузера и не видно, что там находится.

Правильно поведение, но блок `.modal__content` не центрируется по вертикали.

```css
body
{
  margin: 0;
  color: #ACACAC;
}

.modal {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 9999;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.modal--open
{
  display: flex;
}

.modal__content
{
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.modal__header
{
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #484848;
}

.modal__body
{
  min-height: 200px;
  background-color: #252525;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal modal--open">
  <div class="modal__content">
    <div class="modal__header">Заголовок</div>
    <div class="modal__body">Контент</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Не правильное поведение, блок центрируется по центру, но обрезается сверху, если не влазит по высоте.

```css
body
{
  margin: 0;
  color: #ACACAC;
}

.modal {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 9999;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; /* Так мы центрируем */
  flex-direction: column;
}

.modal--open
{
  display: flex;
}

.modal__content
{
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.modal__header
{
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #484848;
}

.modal__body
{
  min-height: 200px;
  background-color: #252525;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal modal--open">
  <div class="modal__content">
    <div class="modal__header">Заголовок</div>
    <div class="modal__body">Контент</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Видео работы реальной модалки: [Видео на YouTube](https://youtu.be/J8Ypru6EcZk)

В начале видео, как должна работать модалка (Если не использовать justify-content: center для центрирования по вертикали), во второй части - как работает с данным свойством (то есть , обрезается верх).

Comment: Обоснуйте минус.

Comment: Да вы смеетесь? То есть вы задали определённую в пикселях величину отступов, определенную высоту, - в пикселях снова, замечу! И ожидаете, что на маленьком экране будет выглядеть так же, как и на крупном?

Comment: Нет, я ожидаю увидеть прокрутку, это же логично.

Comment: Как по мне, ваш вопрос подразумевает, что окно закономерно не умещается на странице. В любом случае, вы сделали элемент с зафиксированной позицией. Как по-вашему он тогда будет прокручиваться? Он не состоит позиционно теперь в body, на ширину его не влияет. Может, вы хотели сделать прокручивающийся контент в модальном окне? Вам для начала нужно сделать адекватный размер модального окна, чтобы оно не торчало за пределы body, а потом уже решать проблемы с прокруткой *в этом модальном окне*.

Comment: "Может, вы хотели сделать прокручивающийся контент в модальном окне?" - так это и пытается сделаться, как видите у .modal есть overflow: auto, что и создает скролл (видно, что можно прокрутить до нижней границы, даже с отступами), но верх модального окна уходит за верхнюю границу. И это только, если контент выше окна браузера. Причем тут размеры? Причем? Ну чего вы вечно пытаетесь казаться такими умными и пишите такую фигню?

Comment: Куда оверфлоу авто то?))) У вас то оверфлоу нету, у вас тело не переполняется! Ваше модальное окно имеет зафиксированную позицию и ***не является наследником боди***. Я не могу понять, как можно сделать элемент с зафиксированной позицией и ожидать что оно прокрутится куда-то

Comment: Причем тут боди вообще? Если скролл должен быть именно у блока .modal?

Comment: Вы бы сначала определились, что должно переполниться? Если бы ваше модальное окно состояло в боди, было бы шире боди, то произошел бы оверфлоу. Оверфлоу происходит в том случае, если элемент содержит какой-то другой элемент, который превышает его размеры. В вашем случае это не так.

Comment: Нет, это не так работает, скролл не может быть у блока модал, там прокручиваться нечему. Он спокойно занимает всю ширину и уходит за пределы. Вы по аналогии можете себе представить, что ваш модал "застрял в текстурках"

Comment: " Оверфлоу не происходит в том случае" извините, лишнее "не" тут, отредактировал сообщение

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135389/discussion-between-oliver-patterson-and-great-tech).

Answer (score 0):

Просто уберите отступы в пикселах

```css
.modal {
  z-index: 9999;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
}

.modal__content
{
  width: 60%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.modal__header
{
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #484848;
}

.modal__body
{
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  background-color: #252525;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal__content">
    <div class="modal__header">       </div>
    <div class="modal__body">         </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я добавил вариант без отступов, чем это помогло?

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: overflow если я вас правильно понял нужно вешать на дочерний блок modal__body