# Проблемы с height 100% и вертикальным центрированием и последующим отображением на мобилках с мелкой высотой экрана

Tags: css, веб-программирование, вёрстка

Есть два div'a и оболочка .outer, которая флексит и выравнивает по вертикали своё содержимое .inner относительно веб страницы. Предлагаю рассмотреть код, очень простой

```css
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(54, 54, 54);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.outer{
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.inner{
    background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/Mfws8xG/b76f1d3521154c1e9b4da31ca19b17ad.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height: 708px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner"></div>
    </div>
```

Проблема в том что при норм высоте окно просмотра, все по центру и шрек есть.
[image]
А при маленькой высоте просмотра пол головы шрека нет, а скролбар не помогает. Как решить это?
[image]
На див натянул Шрека что бы было видно что див пропадает

Answer (score 1):

Шрек персонаж уважаемый, не надо его натягивать. Уберите у класса outer align-items: center и Шрек предстанет перед вами во всей красе

Comment: Спасибо большое и вправду помогло. Но ведь вертикальное центрирование мне все еще нужно. Как можно сделать так что бы когда надо и есть пространство то Шрек центрировался по вертикали, а когда не надо это свойство убиралось? При условии что Шрек будет расти и его длина не всегда известна.

Comment: попробуйте с медиа запросами поиграться

Comment: @SergeyBogdanets, а может есть идеи для этого [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1398114/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0)? Ведь окно может быть разной высоты и медиа не пропишешь, ибо при большом количестве контента, даже на декстопе произойдет такое.

Answer (score 1):

В классе outer - *height=auto;*

В классе inner - *background-repeat: no-repeat;*

Для центровки фона есть свойство *background-position: center;*

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, если применить height:auto, центрирования блока флексами не сработает.

А на счет центрирования фона, мне нужно центрировать именно блок див, а фон натянут для наглядности. Но еще раз спасибо!